# Applications of infinite square well/particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy, applied-physics

I know of only two instances where the infinite square well is an adequate model for experimental behaviour: the [absorption wavelengths of cyanine dyes](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed084p1840), and extremely small semiconductors to which electrons are confined, i.e. "[quantum dots](https://physicsopenlab.org/2015/11/20/quantum-dots-a-true-particle-in-a-box-system/)".

([This previous StackExchange answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37706/) mentioned quantum lasers, but wasn't quite cited enough and was more about the finite square well.)

My question is whether there might be other instances in which we see *nearly infinite* square well behaviour. It's true that "owing to its highly approximate character there is little reason to expect that it can yield quantitative agreement with experimental [data,"](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed084p1840) but, perhaps naïvely, I am hoping that there might be a few more examples.

Comment: The better example would have been radioactive decay that can model the nucleus as a square well.

Comment: No, you are very mistaken. Even back during Schrödinger's original paper describing quantum mechanics and solving the four simple potential problems, it is kinda known that these potential problems are of incredibly wide applicability, just that the details will be a little off because of how simple they are. Would the whole field of statistical thermodynamics satisfy you in how general they are applicable?